# How do i make all circles flicker

Tags: java, processing

i am trying to make all the circles i draw flicker in my code. i am currently able to make the latest circle that was drawn to flicker but the goal is to make all the circles on the canvas flicker.
here is my code;

```processing
float colour = random(256);
final int DIAM = 20;
final int MAX_NUM = 1000;
int numPointsX = 0;
int numPointsY = 0;
int [] xPos = new int[MAX_NUM];
int [] yPos = new int [MAX_NUM];
boolean start = false;

void setup() {
    size (500, 500);
}

void draw() {
    if (start) {
        if (xPos[numPointsX-1] > 0 || (yPos[numPointsY-1]>0)) {
            fill(random(256), random(256), random(256));
            circle(xPos[numPointsX-1], yPos[numPointsY-1], DIAM);
        }
    }
    
    println(xPos[0]);
}

void mouseClicked() {
    insertXandY();
}

void insertXandY() {
    int x = mouseX;
    int y = mouseY;
    
    xPos[numPointsX] = x;
    yPos[numPointsY] = y;
    
    numPointsX += 1;
    numPointsY += 1;
    start = true;
}
```

Comment: What is this code? Java?

Comment: Please add the relevant programming language tag and also please provide a [mre] with sufficient details.

Comment: It's probably Processing https://processing.org/ ... based on java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw all the circles in a loop with a different color in each frame:

```java
void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(random(256), random(256), random(256));
    for (int i = 0; i< numPointsX; ++i) {
        circle(xPos[i], yPos[i], DIAM);
    }
}
```

---

Complete example:

```java
float colour = random(256);
final int DIAM = 20;
final int MAX_NUM = 1000;
int numPointsX = 0;
int numPointsY = 0;
int [] xPos = new int[MAX_NUM];
int [] yPos = new int [MAX_NUM];
boolean start = false;

void setup() {
    size (500, 500);
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(random(256), random(256), random(256));
    for (int i = 0; i< numPointsX; ++i) {
        circle(xPos[i], yPos[i], DIAM);
    }
}

void mouseClicked() {
    insertXandY();
}

void insertXandY() {
    int x = mouseX;
    int y = mouseY;
    
    xPos[numPointsX] = x;
    yPos[numPointsY] = y;
    
    numPointsX += 1;
    numPointsY += 1;
    start = true;
}
```

Comment: @processingboy1 No it is not erased. The code in my answer works fine. The code is tested. How can it be that you can't just copy the code. I've added the entire example to the answer.